# can we use MDX to query tabular model in microsoft Azure analysis services?

Tags: azure, dax, mdx, ssas-tabular

We are in the process of moving from inhouse to cloud(MS Azure). I was told by one of the developer that tabular model in Azure Analysis Services does not support MDX and so we have to move towards DAX. I checked online and could not find any evidence to strongly confirm the case. Can someone point me in right direction to get the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

We have some tabular model in azure cloud and we still can querying model through mdx, but in some case for performance reason we use DAX.